# Function not returning multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, function

The function below is returning one record instead of multiple, it's a `Scalar-valued` function I created ...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [_SMDBA_].[ASSETTAG](@ticket int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here (asset#)
    DECLARE @assettag VARCHAR(MAX)

    -- Query to return all the tasset #s

    SELECT @assettag = "Asset/Tag #" 
    FROM sde."_SMDBA_"."Inventory Items"
    WHERE "Configuration ID" = (SELECT "Client ID" 
                                FROM sde."_SMDBA_"."Incident" 
                                WHERE "Incident #"=@ticket)


    -- Return the result of the function 
    RETURN @assettag
END
```

Any idea how to return multiple results?

---

@Andriy M Thank you very much !! I'm fairly new to tsql, so I created the function based on my logic !

The purpose of my function was to display delimited string values of a column (please don't ask me why), here is my finale function that is currently working fine, let me know if there is something to improve and/or change :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [_SMDBA_].[ASSETTAG3](@ticket int)
RETURNS  @result TABLE
(Asset# nvarchar(50))

AS
BEGIN 
    Declare @concat varchar(50) 
    set @concat=''

    SELECT @concat=@concat + "Asset/Tag #" +' / ' from sde."_SMDBA_"."Inventory Items"
         where "Configuration ID"=(select "Client ID" from "_SMDBA_"."Clients" where "Client Name"=(select "Req Full Name" from "_SMDBA_"."Incident" where "Incident #"=(@ticket)))

INSERT into @result 
select @concat

RETURN
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nazim! Please consolidate your answers. While it's generally ok to answer your own question, in some cases even with multiple answers, here it seems that later answers make the previous obsolete. It's better to delete previous answers or use the 'edit' functionality to update either your question or your answer. I started a discussion on [meta about this Q](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197702/what-to-do-when-an-author-writes-multiple-answers-to-develop-the-solution-while). SO is not a discussion forum, and chronology does not display well here.

Answer (score 3):

In the `RETURNS` section, you must specify a `TABLE` rather than a scalar value.

Example:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [_SMDBA_].[ASSETTAG](@ticket int)
RETURNS @Result TABLE  --Notice the return type is a table
(
    -- Table Schema
    AssetTag VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS 
BEGIN

    -- Insert data into @Result
    INSERT INTO @Result 
    SELECT 'Tag A'

    INSERT INTO @Result 
    SELECT 'Tag B'

    -- Return Table
    RETURN @Result

END
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scalar** functions return a single value. If you need multiple values you need a **Table-Valued** function.

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more detail on Table-Valued functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-created my function as follow, but still returning one record

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [_SMDBA_].[ASSETTAG2](@ticket int)
    RETURNS @result TABLE 
    (


    ticket nvarchar(10) NULL

    )

    AS
    BEGIN 
        Declare
            @Asset_Tag nvarchar(10);

    SELECT 
            @Asset_Tag = "Asset/Tag #" from sde."_SMDBA_"."Inventory Items"
            where "Configuration ID"=(select "Client ID" from sde."_SMDBA_"."Incident" where "Incident #"=@ticket)

    IF @ticket IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT @result
    SELECT @Asset_Tag
    END;

    RETURN;
    end;
```

Comment: Do **not** use a variable. Insert the rows into the `@result` table directly using `INSERT ... SELECT`. Still better, define your function as an *inline* table-valued function: `CREATE FUNCTION ... (...) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT "Asset/Tag #" FROM ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go ....this work :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [_SMDBA_].[ASSETTAG3](@ticket int)
RETURNS  @result TABLE
(Asset# nvarchar(10))

AS
BEGIN 

    INSERT into @result 
        SELECT "Asset/Tag #" from sde."_SMDBA_"."Inventory Items"
            where "Configuration ID"=(select "Client ID" from sde."_SMDBA_"."Incident" where "Incident #"=@ticket)

    RETURN
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a multi-statement table valued function. Here's an inline table-valued function doing the same:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [_SMDBA_].[ASSETTAG3] (@ticket int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT "Asset/Tag #" AS "Asset#"
    FROM sde."_SMDBA_"."Inventory Items"
    WHERE "Configuration ID" = (
        SELECT "Client ID"
        FROM sde."_SMDBA_"."Incident"
        WHERE "Incident #" = @ticket
    )
;
```

An inline TVF is better than a multi-statement TVF in that it opens more possibilities for optimisation when used in complex queries: the optimiser will not prepare a separate execution plan for it but instead will consider its body as part of the whole query so as to come up with best possible execution plan.

That is not the case with a multi-statement function, which is more like a black box with regard to the outer query it is being used in, because it always has a separate execution plan from the rest of the query that's calling it.